# Is it OK to take a question asked in another SE site & rephrase it for WB?

Tags: discussion, rules

Specifically, the question I have in mind is [Could bone marrow transplants be used to prevent tissue rejection of trans-species organs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/79881/could-bone-marrow-transplants-be-used-to-prevent-tissue-rejection-of-trans-speci) asked by myself in biology SE some 2 months ago.

I asked it there because I wanted solid science based answers & was looking for potential hints on where I might find any research related to the idea.

It's had some attention but no answers so I was considering a re-post here to take advantage of the (what appears to me to be) larger more eclectic user base in WB.

The tags would, of course, include [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) & [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) (or at the very least [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based)).

Comment: Eclectic userbase? Nah, we're normal. Totally normal...

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms just take the damn complement OK ;p

Answer (score 10):

While it's true that the general rule is that posting the same question on multiple sites in the network is discouraged (and at least Unix & Linux SE has that as a specific reason to close a question, possibly because of their large overlap with Ask Ubuntu and to a lesser extent Super User and Server Fault), the operative word here is **same.**

Broadly speaking, it's fine to ask about the same topic on different sites, in order to get different perspectives, but that doesn't mean that you should take the exact same question text and post it verbatim on multiple sites.

Rather, you should **adapt the question to each audience.**

I haven't looked at this example in particular, but I imagine there are, for example, things that would be taken for granted on Biology SE (say, an earthen environment populated by carbon-based, oxygen-breathing lifeforms) that you might benefit from explicitly stating when asking on Worldbuilding SE.

For example, the best-received (by net vote count) question of mine on Physics SE is [one about faster-than-light travel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/275211/14091), which is a little surprising in a way because their subject scope specifically deals with *mainstream* physics only. [One of my better received answers on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/46678/29) also deals with faster-than-light travel, was accepted, and is very much based in mainstream science. This doesn't mean that one could just transpose the two questions and expect that things work out well. It does, however, show that the same general concept *can* be asked about on both sites, *if* the questions are written appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

[The general rule on Stack Exchange is that cross-posting the same question on different sites is discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). That said, that isn't a hard and fast rule and if you are looking for a different perspective cross-posting can be acceptable. It looks to me like you didn't get any answers over on Biology because your question is very speculative and they prefer to deal in known answers. So, it seems to me like cross-posting your question here isn't... well, out of the question, because you are likely to get different, useful, speculative responses here.

If you do post the question it's recommended that you link the original question in your new question and give an explanation for why you are asking it again.

Comment: _**"your question is very speculative"**_ I actually take some small degree of offence at that, I feel there's not an actual shred of speculation in it, do you think you could point it out to me ~ bearing in mind the meaning of the word of course _"speculation : the forming of a theory or **conjecture without firm evidence**."_ ;)

Comment: ^ what I mean to say of course is I worked very hard when I originally formulated the Biology SE question to remove any wildly speculative elements, stick very closely to facts & couch it in in terms of wouldn't this be a reasonable approach to research ~ so if you feel I failed at that I'd be interested to know why.

Comment: @Pelinore By "speculative" I simply meant that the answer to your question is not known. I didn't mean to imply that the idea was implausible or unsupported. But this isn't the place to discuss the contents of the question itself.

Comment: ^ _"isn't the place to discuss the contents of the question itself"_ ~ true.

Comment: Thanks for the link ~ that was what I was looking for (but failed to find, didn't think to look in the main SE meta) ~ I'll give it a close read.

Comment: Questions "often enough" get transferred to another group if deemed more appropriate there, This is what you are doing, albeit informally., You could ask admins to do this for you or ... .

Comment: There's one caveat to the cross-posting rule: if the question is closed as off-topic, and you're redirected to a SE site where it *would* be off-topic, it's perfectly fine to re-ask the question there as long as a) the question doesn't get migrated and b) the question actually *is* on-topic on the other site. On several occasions I've seen people cross-post a question based on a mistaken suggestion, only to see it get closed all over again.

Comment: I'll note that that caveat doesn't apply to this particular question because it's still open, and OP was not redirected here by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to your question is sure, modify the question to meet the expectations of Worldbuilding.SE and there's no problem.

But I have a problem with your reason to do so.  You asked the question in the correct forum — quite literally the best forum for the question — and you want it here because you didn't like the attention it received and/or the answers you received.

That suggests you really want to ask the same question and want to only change the window dressing to slide it in under our rules, hoping that someone here might do a better job than there.

The entire premise of the opposition to [A proposal to finalize the "are real world questions on-topic" debate](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate) was that the other forums were far better suited to answer the question and far more likely to provide you with an authoritative answer.  Therefore, we shouldn't be letting people clog up our own queues with those questions.

Ultimately, the rule allowing real-world questions was adopted (I personally approve).  However, *this should never be an excuse to abuse the privilege,* and what you're telling us is that you want to abuse the privilege.  You didn't get what you wanted there, so you want to give it a shot here, even though there's a lower statistical chance of getting the answer you want here.  Honestly, if it were possible to close due to being a duplicate on another stack, it would be (and should be).

So, yes, there's no problem with it.  But if you'll forgive the moment of astronomical arrogance: thou shalt not abuse the privilege neither make a habit of it therein.

Comment: RE " you want it here because you didn't like the attention it received and/or the answers you received." The OP said no answers. So it seems quite reasonable to post it elsewhere in that case. As for " you want it here because you didn't like the attention it received and/or the answers you received." That's a bit rich. Imputing motivations to the OP that may not be justified. The OP has been open about what he is doing. Even asking if it was OK.

Comment: @a4android, he received an answer the day after posting this question.

Comment: That doesn't change my point. When he posted he hadn't had any answers. Apart from paragraphs 1 and 6 your answer is mostly moralizing commentary and doesn't constitute an answer to the question.